Submit 2 forms with one button with no errors on both forms
I'm trying to to submit 2 forms on the same screen with one button if no errors on both forms. Each form goes to a separate SharePoint list. Currently, If form 1 is filled out correctly it will always submit even if form 2 has an error and because form 2 has errors it doesn't submit. How can I get both forms to submit if both forms don't have errors?

Your question is not clear. Are you describing current, unwanted behaviour or are you describing desired future behaviour?

You may want to separate form validation and submitting the forms into different units. For example, create a text box for each form. The formula in the text box checks each field in the form with the rules you want to apply for error checking. If there are errors, the formula returns "false". If there are no errors, the formula returns "true".
For the submit button, you can now create conditions with the If() statement and only submit the forms if both text boxes are set to true.
Example:
Form1 can only be submitted if both the Title control and the Cost control are filled in. The controls are named TitleInput and CostInput.
Form2 can only be submitted if both the Colour control and the Size control are filled in. The controls are named ColourInput and SizeInput.
The two textboxes are called Form1Validation and Form2Validation, and the formulas for the text boxes then look like this:
!Blank(TitleInput.Text) && !Blank(CostInput.Text)
!Blank(ColourInput.Text) && !Blank(SizeInput.Text)
Now you can use this formula in the OnSelect property of the button:
If(Form1Validation.Text = true && Form2Validation.Text = true,
   SubmitForm(Form1); SubmitForm(Form2),
// else
  set(varShowErrorMessage,true)

You can have another text box that becomes visible when varErrorMessage is true. Hide the Form1Validation and Form2Validation text boxes when done with testing.
That's the concept, and I'm using this approach all the time. I have not tested these particular formulas, though, since, I wrote it all directly into the answer box here.

Each form has about 20 or so cards it. Doing this method seems like it would get a little messy. Seems like there should be more elegant way to do this.

how do you establish that the form is valid, then? wait for the submit to fail? Yes, error catching like that is more work, but it leaves you in control. If you just string the two submit commands, you have no control. The first one will submit if without errors, but you can't prevent the first form from submitting in case the second form has errors, if you have to wait for the submit of the second form to fail. Hence you need to check beforehand, if both forms are clean, then submit both, otherwise sumit neither.
